# Custom prompt not have any effect in my langchain

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I am using langchain to read my excel data and respond accordingly, it works ok but i want the answer to be as a json and i may wish for any other requirements , for that i am trying to add my prompt , But its not working

```
  def test_excel(self, query="give me price for samsung"):
    loader = UnstructuredExcelLoader("assets/Master.xlsx", mode="elements")
    documents = loader.load()
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
    documents = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents, embeddings)
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

    chat_history = []

    custom_template = """ 
       Provide your answer in JSON format with the following keys: 
           Brand, Screen Size, Box size, price, Recommendation
    Chat History:
    {chat_history}
    Follow Up Input: {question}
    Standalone question:"""

    CUSTOM_QUESTION_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template(custom_template)

    qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(temperature=0), vectorstore.as_retriever(),
                                               condense_question_prompt=CUSTOM_QUESTION_PROMPT,
                                               memory=memory
                                               )
    result = qa({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
   
    return result
```

Whatever i am telling langchain in my prompt, it does not have any effect

any idea what i am doing wrong please

Comment: [PrivateDocBot](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/PrivateDocBot)

Created using langchain and chainlit 

It also streams using langchain just like ChatGpt it displays word by word and works locally on PDF data. ‍ 

code reference.

Answer (score 0):

Base on documentaion:
The ConversationalRetrievalQA chain builds on RetrievalQAChain to provide a chat history component.

It first combines the chat history (either explicitly passed in or retrieved from the provided memory) and the question into a standalone question, then looks up relevant documents from the retriever, and finally passes those documents and the question to a question-answering chain to return a response.

So it has two step, you used condense_question_prompt=CUSTOM_QUESTION_PROMPT
That use in first step, you should use this arg for step two
combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": your prompt},